# Etch-A-Sketch with a changing color button?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jbutton, jcolorchooser

I tried to add a button which prompts a color palette (given by a class I looked up called JColorChooser) to change the color of the line drawn. After I click on the button (which I named to "Change color") and pick out a color from the palette and try to redraw, the color of the line remains black and this message pops up on my console:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Etch_A_Sketch.actionPerformed(Etch_A_Sketch.java:45)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
```

etc... the list goes on

Here is what I have so far for the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Etch_A_Sketch implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, ActionListener
{
    JFrame window;
    Container content;
    int mouseX,mouseY,oldX,oldY;
    JLabel coords;
    JButton color;
    Color lineColor = Color.black;


    public Etch_A_Sketch()
    {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Classic Etch a Sketch");
        content = window.getContentPane();
        content.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
        color = new JButton("Change color");
        color.addActionListener(this);

        coords = new JLabel();
        coords.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.ITALIC + Font.BOLD, 32));

        content.add(color);
        content.add( coords); 
        content.addMouseListener(this);
        content.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        window.setSize(640,480);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == color)
        {
            lineColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(window, "Pick a color", lineColor);
            if(lineColor != null)
            {
                window.getContentPane().setBackground(lineColor);
            }
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent me)
    {
        mouseX = me.getX();
        mouseY = me.getY();
        reportCoords("Mouse clicked at: " + mouseX + "," + mouseY);

    }
    public void mousePressed( MouseEvent me)
    {
        mouseX = me.getX();
        mouseY = me.getY();
        reportCoords("Mouse Pressed at: " + mouseX + "," + mouseY);

    }

    public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent me)
    {
        mouseX = me.getX();
        mouseY = me.getY();
        reportCoords("Mouse released at: " + mouseX + "," + mouseY);

    }

    public void mouseExited( MouseEvent me)
    {
        mouseX = me.getX();
        mouseY = me.getY();
        reportCoords("Mouse exited at: " + mouseX + "," + mouseY);

    }

    public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent me)
    {
        mouseX = me.getX();
        mouseY = me.getY();
        reportCoords("Mouse Entered at: " + mouseX + "," + mouseY);

    }

    public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent me)
    {
        mouseX = me.getX();
        mouseY = me.getY();

        if (oldX ==0 )
        {
            oldX=mouseX;
            oldY=mouseY;
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = content.getGraphics();
        g.drawLine( oldX,oldY, mouseX, mouseY );
        oldX = mouseX;
        oldY = mouseY;
        reportCoords("Mouse Dragged at: " + mouseX + "," + mouseY);

    }

    public void mouseMoved( MouseEvent me)
    {
        mouseX = me.getX();
        mouseY = me.getY();
        reportCoords("Mouse Moved at: " + mouseX + "," + mouseY);

}



// ..............................................................


    public static void main( String[] args)
    {
        new Etch_A_Sketch();
    }

    private void reportCoords( String msg )
    {
        coords.setText( msg ); 
    }
}
```

All I want to achieve is to be able to change the color of the line to the color choice of the user.

Comment: Line 45 of your given code appears to be a blank line. Did you not include all of your code? What is line 45?

Comment: I posted everything that I have. I figured the actionPerformed() method is the root of my problem, but I don't really know what you mean by it being a blank line.

Comment: Line 45 is the line after the closing brace of the `actionPerformed()` method.

Comment: Never mind my comments. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in the constructor:

```
public Etch_A_Sketch()
{
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Classic Etch a Sketch");
    content = window.getContentPane();
    content.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
    color = new JButton("Change color");
    color.addActionListener(this);

    coords = new JLabel();
    coords.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.ITALIC + Font.BOLD, 32));

    content.add(color);
    content.add( coords); 
    content.addMouseListener(this);
    content.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    window.setSize(640,480);
    window.setVisible(true);
}
```

This line:

```
JFrame window = new JFrame("Classic Etch a Sketch");
```

creates a local variable in the constructor called `window`. All the initialization is therefore done to the local variable, which goes out of scope when the constructor terminates. The `actionPerformed()` method uses the instance variable, which is not yet initialized, and therefore `null`. Therefore, when `window.getContentPane()` is called from within `actionPerformed()`, it is an attempt to invoke a method on a `null` reference, resulting in a `NullPointerException`.

To fix the problem, instead of declaring a local variable in the constructor, like this:

```
JFrame window = new JFrame("Classic Etch a Sketch");
```

use the already-declared instance variable:

```
window = new JFrame("Classic Etch a Sketch");
```